# how to show filter choices by default on lists

Tags: filter

my list has 501 records and I was expecting that "Show filter choices" will be available on each drop down columns but it this didn't happen.
when i try typing ?Filter=1 at the end of the URL, I see the view that I want.
Do you know how to keep this as the default view

Comment: can you please add some more details regarding this ,as how you are thinking to implement this